# Decomposing Single Crossing Minor Free graphs

Tags: graph-theory

We know that for a single-crossing graph *H* of size *h*, there exists a constant *c<sub>h</sub>* whose value depends only on *h*, such that every four-connected component of an *H*-minor-free graph is either a planar graph or of treewidth at most *c<sub>h</sub>*.

I would like to know if some sort of the reverse of this also holds. That is, can we say for every such graph *G* whose four-connected components are of treewidth is at most *w* or a planar graph, there exists a constant *c<sub>w</sub>* whose value depends only on *w* and single-crossing graphs *H<sub>1</sub>, H<sub>2</sub>, ..., H<sub>l</sub>* each of size at most *c<sub>w</sub>*, such that *G* belongs to the union of *H_i*-minor free-graphs for each *i* in *1, 2, ..., l*?

Comment: When you say 4-connected do you mean wrt edge cuts or vertex cuts?

Comment: I mean vertex connectivity.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood your statement correctly, then it is false:

In a graph of maximum degree $3$ the $4$-connected components are all single vertices (and therefore planar AND of treewidth $\leq 1$). However we can make graphs of maximum degree 3 that contain arbitrarily large cliques as minors.

Comment: the 3-clique sum decomposition is perhaps what the OP is referring to. Wouldn’t we get a decomposition into a $K_4$ and a graph with minimum degree at $4$ the first time we try the decomposition. Further would this be a strong $3$ cut in the sense of Demaine et al?